# Keychain access error 25308 (errSecInteractionNotAllowed)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, keychain

In one of my iOS app, I am seeing multiple crashes while accessing the Keychain (in both cases i.e. setting an item & getting an item) and the error code is **25308**. 
Few details:
1) I am using a 3rd party keychain wrapper https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess 
 
2) The accessibility option is set to '**whenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly**'
3) This is not happening to all users. I am unable to reproduce it by any chance.
4) I am accessing keychain at few places in AppDelegate. Few crashes are reported on app launch and few are reported on Firebase token refresh notification observer method. 
 
5) In didFinishLaunch, I am trying to access the value for a keychain item where as in Firebase token refresh, I am trying to set the new token value to the keychain.

On my findings I understood that this error code **25308** will be returned **when user tries to access the keychain when a device is in locked state.** But my Fabric (crash reporting tool) shows that the **'App is in Focus'** in all these crashes. 
So this got me confused with multiple questions like:

1) What else cases can throw this error 25308 other than device unlocked state? 
2) Does firebase token refresh notification causes this background launching of app ? If so, how can I reproduce this. (One supporting thing here is I know that app was not uninstalled)

**Update on 01/03:**
It seems like the root cause for this is *'App is being launched when **Firebase** generates a new token and this launch is happening when device is in locked state, hence keychain access is throwing such error 25308.'* So is anyone aware how a new firebase token launches the app which is already in terminated state??

Appreciate your responses on this. Thanks..